# Fourier series for $\phi(x) = x$ on $[-l,l]$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-series

> The function $\phi(x) = x$ on the interval $[-l,l]$ has the Fourier series
>   $$x = \frac{2 l}{\pi}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{m+1}}{m}\sin\left(\frac{m\pi x}{l} \right) = \frac{2 l}{\pi}\left(\sin\left(\frac{\pi x}{l} \right) - \frac{1}{2}\sin\left(\frac{2\pi x}{l} \right) + \frac{1}{3}\sin\left(\frac{3\pi x}{l} \right) - \ldots \right)$$
>   a.) Set $x = \frac{l}{2}$ to find the sum of the series
>   $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{2n + 1} = 1 - \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{5} - \frac{1}{7} + \ldots$$
>   b.) Integrate the series term-by-term to find the Fourier series for $\frac{1}{2}x^2$, up tp a constant of integration (which is then the $\frac{1}{2}A_0$ term in the cosine series). Find the $A_0$ using the standard formula to completely determine the series.
>   c.) Set $x = 0$ in your solution to part a.) and find the sum $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^2}$.
>   d.) Integrate the series again, and find the sine series for $x^3 - l^2 x$.
>   e.) Set $x - \frac{l}{2}$ to find the sum of the series 
>   $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}}{(2n + 1)^3} = 1 - \frac{1}{3^3} + \frac{1}{5^3} - \frac{1}{7^3} + \ldots$$
>   f.) Integrate one last time to find the cosine series for $x^4 - 2l^2 x^2$. Remember, you'll need to find the constant term separately.
>   g.) Finally, put $x = 0$ in your series in part d.) to find the sum $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^4}$

Attempted solution a.) - Letting $x = \frac{l}{2}$ then 
\begin{align*}
\frac{l}{2} &= \frac{2l}{\pi}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{m+1}}{m}\sin\left(\frac{m\pi(l/2)}{l} \right) = \frac{2l}{\pi}\left(\sin\left(\frac{\pi(l/2)}{l}\right) - \frac{1}{2}\sin\left(\frac{2\pi (l/2)}{l}\right) + \frac{1}{3}\sin\left(\frac{3\pi(l/2)}{l}\right) - \ldots \right)\\
&\Rightarrow \sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{m+1}}{m}\sin\left(\frac{m\pi}{2}\right) = \left(\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right) - \frac{1}{2}\sin(\pi) + \frac{1}{3}\sin\left(\frac{3\pi}{2}\right) - \frac{1}{4}\sin\left(\frac{4\pi}{2}\right) + \frac{1}{5}\sin\left(\frac{5\pi}{2}\right) \right)
\end{align*}
Note that 
$$\sin\left(\frac{m\pi}{2}\right) = \begin{cases}
0, \ \ &\text{if} \ m \ \text{is even}, \ m = 2n, n=0,1,2,\ldots\\
(-1)^n \ \ &\text{if} \ m \ \text{is odd}, \ m = 2n+1, n = 0,1,2,\ldots
\end{cases}$$
Then we have 
\begin{align*}
\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{m+1}}{m}\sin\left(\frac{m\pi}{2}\right) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{2n+1+1\text{?}}}{2n+1}(-1)^{n} &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{3n+2}}{2n+1}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}}{2n+1}\\
&= 1 - \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{5} - \frac{1}{7}\\
&= \frac{\pi}{4}
\end{align*}

Attempted solution b.) - We want to integrate $$x = \frac{2l}{\pi}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{m+1}}{m}\sin\left(\frac{m\pi x}{l}\right)$$
to find the Fourier series for $\frac{1}{2}x^2$. Thus,
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{2}x^2 + \tau &= \frac{2l}{\pi}\int \sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{m+1}}{m}\sin\left(\frac{m\pi x}{l}\right)dx\\
&= \frac{2l}{\pi}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{(-1)^{m+1}}{m}\frac{-1l}{m\pi}\cos\left(\frac{m\pi x}{l}\right) + \tau_m \right)\\
&= \frac{2l^2}{\pi^2}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{(-1)^m}{m^2}\cos\left(\frac{m\pi x}{l} \right) + \tau_m \right)\\
\Rightarrow \frac{1}{2}x^2 &= \frac{2l^2}{\pi^2}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^m}{m^2}\cos\left(\frac{m\pi x}{l}\right) + \tilde{\tau}
\end{align*}
where $\tilde{\tau} = \frac{2l^2}{\pi^2}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\tau_m - \tau$. Since this is a Fourier cosine series for $\frac{1}{2}x^2$ we get $\tilde{\tau}$ by using the standard formula to completely determine the series. Thus
$$\tilde{\tau} = \frac{1}{2}A_0 = \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{l}\int_{-l}^{l}\frac{1}{2}x^2 dx = \frac{l^2}{6}$$
Therefore, 
$$\frac{1}{2}x^2 = \frac{2l^2}{\pi^2}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^m}{m^2}\cos\left(\frac{m\pi x}{l}\right) + \frac{l^2}{6}$$

Attempted solution c.) - Let $x = 0$ for our solution to part a.). Then we have 
\begin{align*}
0 &= \frac{2l^2}{\pi^2}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^m}{m^2} + \frac{l^2}{6}\\
&\Rightarrow \frac{2l^2}{\pi^2}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^m}{m^2} = -\frac{l^2}{6}\\
&\Rightarrow \sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{m+1}}{m^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{12}
\end{align*}

Attempted solution d.) - We know that $$\frac{1}{2}x^2 = \frac{2l^2}{\pi^2}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^m}{m^2}\cos\left(\frac{m\pi x}{l}\right) + \frac{l^2}{6}$$ or that
$$\frac{1}{2}x^2 - \frac{l^2}{6} = \frac{4l^2}{\pi^2}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^m}{m^2}\cos\left(\frac{m\pi x}{l}\right)$$
Thus integrating the series we have 
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{6}x^3 - \frac{l^2}{6}x &= \frac{2l^2}{\pi^2}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{m}}{m^2}\frac{l}{m\pi}\sin\left(\frac{m\pi x}{l}\right) + \xi\\
&= \frac{2l^3}{\pi^3}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{m}}{m^3}\sin\left(\frac{m\pi x}{l}\right) + \xi
\end{align*}
Then
$$\xi = \frac{1}{2l}\int_{-l}^{l}\frac{1}{6}x^3 - \frac{l^2}{6}x dx 0$$
Therefore
$$x^3 - l^2x = \frac{12l^3}{\pi^3}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{m}}{m^3}\sin\left(\frac{m\pi x}{l}\right)$$

Attempted solution e.) - Setting $x = \frac{l}{2}$ we get 
\begin{align*}
&\left(\frac{l}{2} \right)^3 - l^2\left(\frac{l}{2}\right) = \frac{12l^2}{\pi^3}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{m}}{m^3}\sin\left(\frac{m\pi (l/2)}{l}\right)\\
 &= \frac{12l^2}{\pi^3}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{m}}{m^3}\sin\left(\frac{m\pi (l/2)}{l}\right) = \frac{12l^2}{\pi^3}\left(-\sin\left(\frac{\pi(l/2)}{l}\right) + \frac{1}{8}\sin\left(\frac{2\pi (l/2)}{l}\right) - \frac{1}{27}\sin\left(\frac{3\pi(l/2)}{l}\right) + \ldots \right)\\
&\Rightarrow \sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^m}{m^3}\sin\left(\frac{m\pi}{2}\right) = \left(-\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right) + \frac{1}{8}\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{2}\right) - \frac{1}{27}\sin\left(\frac{3\pi}{2}\right) + \ldots \right)
\end{align*}
Note that 
$$\sin\left(\frac{m\pi}{2}\right) = \begin{cases}
0, \ \ &\text{if} \ m \ \text{is even}, \ m = 2n, n=0,1,2,\ldots\\
(-1)^n \ \ &\text{if} \ m \ \text{is odd}, \ m = 2n+1, n = 0,1,2,\ldots
\end{cases}$$
Then we have 
\begin{align*}
\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^m}{m^3}\sin\left(\frac{m\pi}{2}\right) &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{2n+2}}{(2n+1)^3}(-1)^n\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{3n+2}}{(2n+1)^3}\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}}{(2n+1)^3}\\
&= 1 - \frac{1}{3^3} + \frac{1}{5^3} - \frac{1}{7^3} + \ldots\\
&= \frac{\pi^3}{32}
\end{align*}

Attempted solution f.) - We know that 
$$x^3 - l^2x = \frac{12l^3}{\pi^3}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{m}}{m^3}\sin\left(\frac{m\pi x}{l}\right)$$
Integrating this series we get
\begin{align*}
\frac{x^4}{4} - \frac{l^2 x^2}{2} &= \frac{12l^3}{\pi^3}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{m}}{m^3}\left(-\frac{l}{m\pi} \right)\cos\left(\frac{m\pi x}{l}\right) + \eta\\
&= \frac{12l^4}{\pi^4}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{m+1}}{m^4}\cos\left(\frac{m\pi x}{l}\right) + \eta
\end{align*}
Then,
$$\eta = \frac{1}{2l}\int_{-l}^{l}\frac{x^4}{4} - \frac{l^2 x^2}{2}dx = -\frac{7l^4}{60}$$
Therefore,
$$x^4 - 2l^2 x^2 = \frac{48l^4}{\pi^3}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{m+1}}{m^4}\cos\left(\frac{m\pi x}{l}\right) - \frac{7l^4}{15}$$

Attempted solution g.) - Letting $x = 0$ we have 
\begin{align*}
\frac{48l^4}{\pi^3}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{m+1}}{m^4} - \frac{7l^4}{15} &= 0\\
\frac{48l^4}{\pi^3}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{m+1}}{m^4} &= \frac{7l^4}{15}\\
\Rightarrow \sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{m+1}}{m^4} &= \frac{7\pi^4}{720}
\end{align*}

These are all my attempted solutions. Please let me know if there is anything wrong.

Comment: Part c.) would make sense to me if it were $\cos(\cdot)$ rather than $\sin(\cdot)$. Does it mean however to set $x=\epsilon\rightarrow 0$, instead? That is, does it mean to perturb $x$, letting it be nonzero but infinitesimal/vanishing, that one can deal in the first-order Taylor expansion $\sin u \approx u$?

Comment: @thb To be honest I have no idea

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to be obscure. It is possible that you have discovered an error in the problem statement.

Comment: I think in part b) you should not be integrating over $[0,l]$  You probably want limits something like $[0,x]$ integrating over a dummy variable $t$.  You're supposed to come out with a Fourier series for $1/2x^2$ at the end, no?  Going to have to have a variable.

Comment: @sharding4 Yes, I believe so, I am having a hard time with this exercise

Comment: We have the solution for b) [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2327636/integrating-the-fourier-series-to-find-the-fourier-series-of-frac12x2) (I've just checked that the question I've linked is yours and it seems to me the answers are correct...)

Comment: For part a.) you can just directly plug in $x = \frac{l}{2}$ to get the answer. No need to use the notgiven series for arctan.

Comment: @RafaBudría Yes, I agree they are correct yet I do not understand it

Comment: For b) your work is perfect, you simply need to know that the argument into the summation has two terms, one of them being simply $1$: you split the summation in two summations $$-\frac{2 l^2}{\pi^2}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{m+1}}{m^2}\left(\cos\left(\frac{m \pi x}{l}\right) - 1\right)=$$ $$=-\frac{2 l^2}{\pi^2}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{m+1}}{m^2}\left(\cos\left(\frac{m \pi x}{l}\right) \right)+\frac{2 l^2}{\pi^2}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{m+1}}{m^2}$$

Comment: Mmm, for b) you fixed the superior limit and this is not correct. You need a primitive, given leaving the superior limit to change (you have to put $x$ there, with some minor changes as the dummy variable of integration). I've corrected this in my comment and you can see the second summation is constant. In the other post, the answers simply calculate this sum (in terms of the zeta function, easy for such a scholars... :)

Comment: @RafaBudría I think I got it now, made an edit to my answer will include more as I get to the rest

Comment: If anyone has any suggestions for d.) or the rest please let me know that is where I am currently stuck

Comment: @RafaBudría I made more edits to the questions to finish it off