# Integrate the Fourier series to find the sine series for $x^3 - l^2 x$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, fourier-series

> The function $\phi(x) = x$ on the interval $[-l,l]$ has the Fourier series
>   $$x = \frac{2 l}{\pi}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{m+1}}{m}\sin\left(\frac{m\pi x}{l} \right) = \frac{2 l}{\pi}\left(\sin\left(\frac{\pi x}{l} \right) - \frac{1}{2}\sin\left(\frac{2\pi x}{l} \right) + \frac{1}{3}\sin\left(\frac{3\pi x}{l} \right) - \ldots \right)$$
>   Integrate the series again, and find the sine series for $x^3 - l^2 x$.

This question was originally started [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2328910/fourier-series-for-phix-x-on-l-l?noredirect=1#comment4794966_2328910), I am really not sure how to proceed with this. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Attempted solution - (Following the same procedure I took in the link) We know that $$\frac{1}{2}x^2 = \frac{2l^2}{\pi^2}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^m}{m^2}\cos\left(\frac{m\pi x}{l}\right) + \frac{l^2}{6}$$ or that
$$\frac{1}{2}x^2 - \frac{l^2}{6} = \frac{4l^2}{\pi^2}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^m}{m^2}\cos\left(\frac{m\pi x}{l}\right)$$
Thus integrating the series we have 
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{6}x^3 - \frac{l^2}{6}x &= \frac{2l^2}{\pi^2}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{m}}{m^2}\frac{l}{m\pi}\sin\left(\frac{m\pi x}{l}\right) + \xi\\
&= \frac{2l^3}{\pi^3}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{m}}{m^3}\sin\left(\frac{m\pi x}{l}\right) + \xi
\end{align*}
Then
$$\xi = \frac{1}{2l}\int_{-l}^{l}\frac{1}{6}x^3 - \frac{l^2}{6}x dx 0$$
Therefore
$$x^3 - l^2x = \frac{12l^3}{\pi^3}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{m}}{m^3}\sin\left(\frac{m\pi x}{l}\right)$$

I am not sure if this is correct, any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: The calculation of $A_0$ from $0$ to $l$ looks like a problem.  Why not $-l$ to $l$?  The function is odd, so shouldn't have a constant term $l^3/12$, right?

Comment: Also minor error when you factored $1/\pi$ out of the sum, you dropped an $l$ you should have factored out as well.  Fix up the $l^3/\pi^3$ and the constant term, and you should be good.

Comment: @sharding4 For $A_0$ I was simply looking at my notes and there we take the integral of $0$ to $l$ if it was from $-l$ to $l$ then the integral would equal zero. Which error did I make when I factored $1/\pi$ out of the sum I don't see where I did that mistake?

Comment: You should have factored out an $l$ at the same time, $l/\pi$  You factored out the $1/\pi$ and dropped the $l$

Comment: @sharding4 Sorry I am not sure which line you are referring to. Is it mathematically incorrect? If so, could you copy and paste my solution and make the appropriate changes?

Comment: @sharding4 I made an edit to my answer can you check it please?

Comment: Yes that was it.  Looks good to me now